# Fixed mobile header navigation menu tray

Tags: css, menu, header, fixed, tray

I'm a fan of fixed headers on mobile. They allow the user to navigate no matter where they are on the page, very user friendly.

These are great when using full screen over menus for simple brochure websites.

We are developing a site which has numerous sub navigation sections so a menu tray would be more preferable. We get a user friendly menu system and it's fixed in a minimised navigation strip at the top of the mobile screen (launched from a hamburger icon)

We are struggling to find any examples of this? has anyone else considered this?